# Is the EM wave around a capacitor a standing wave or a traveling wave when AC current flows into that capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, capacitance

Please, check the following pdf file.

http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide13.pdf

It looks like that the two conductors of Fig.13.4.6 is just capacitor when AC current flows into that capacitor.

By any chance, is the EM wave around a capacitor a standing wave?
 If not, what is a real world example of a standing EM wave?

Comment: It is not a wave but a quasistatic field. In principle there is a wave field as well but this has extremely low intensity for 50 or so Hz involved in AC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the "quasistatic field". I can find the fact that the quasistatic approximation neglects the second-order electric field contributions from the time derivative of the resulting⎯H in Faraday’s law when the wavelength λ = c/f is much larger than the device size. But my question is "Is EM wave around a capacitor a standing wave or not?". I mean not the large or small problem.